# What is This Error I get everytime after Debugging everytime and It's g++ compiler I'm using

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

The Error I Get After Debugging, When I press a key random key to close the terminal in VS code (integrated) It automatically starts Powershell (integrated) and shows this:

```
PS C:\Users\####\Desktop\CPP> & 'c: \Users\###\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.5.1\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-nukgex502.ouf' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-cdrwtdkv.2c4' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-yiwuqa2b.xmu' '--pid=licrosoft-MIEngine-Pid-iyaavmoy.sbg' '--dbgExe=C: \Program Files\minguW-W64 \mingw64 \bin \gdb.exe ''--interpreter=mi' -2147483643 2147493647
```

This All thing in Debug Consol, After Powershell:

```
    =thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
[New Thread 10432.0x3cd8]
[New Thread 10432.0xe90]
[New Thread 10432.0x24a8]
[New Thread 10432.0x3bc0]

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, main () at C:\Users\#####\Desktop\Cpp\Binary_conversion.cpp:18
18      return 0;
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\opt\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\opt\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
[Thread 10432.0x24a8 exited with code 0]
[Thread 10432.0x3bc0 exited with code 0]
[Thread 10432.0xe90 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 10432) exited normally]
The program 'c:\Users\#####\Desktop\Cpp\Binary_conversion.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

IDK what is this, So can anyone explain to me what is this and How to fix this?

Comment: Can you explain which "this" you have a problem with? This just looks like a transcript of your debug plugin's interaction with the GDB debugger.

Comment: Please post text as text, not screenshots

Comment: I Did the edit of Screenshot